# edit pagelayout not available for few profiles

Tags: lightning

edit pagelayout not available for few profiles, Where to find this setting?
[image]

Comment: Can you share the screen shot of the page where you are not able to see `Edit Page` option, also share a full screenshot, for eg: from which page are you accessing this setting?

Comment: Im trying to access contact object. edit page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=accessing_layout_standard.htm&type=5) you need to have two permission.
I believe one you already have `View Setup and Configuration` that is why you are able to see the setup icon. Check below:

Profile / PS-> Under System Permission check if you have `Customize Application`

Comment: perfect thank you